# To retrieve the value from one dialog box and display it in another dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dialog

I am having a dialog box which ask for your name and address and when you click ok button it opens another dialog where it should display the name and address.I have tried it using ajax post ,but nothing seems to work in the desired way.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.
Here is what I have tried:

**display.php:**

```
<input type="button" id="dialog_open" name="dialog_open" value="dialog_open" ></input>

<form action = "" method="post">
    <div id="dialog"  title="Enter details" style="display:none" >
        Name :<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" id="name" />
        Address: <textarea row="3" col="50" class="form-control input-sm" name="address" id="address" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="show" title="welcome" style="display:none">
        <header style="text-align:center; font-size:20px; font-style:arial">
            <b><?php echo $_POST['keyname']; ?></b>
            <p style="text-align:left; font-size:14px">Address:<?php echo $_POST['keyadd']; ?></p>
        </header>
    </div>
```

**my script code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dialog_open').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Yes" : function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        callback(true);    
                    },
                    "No" : function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');   
                    }
                } 
            });

            function callback(value) {
                if (value) {
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var add = $('#address').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'display.php', 
                        data: {keyname: com,keyadd: add},
                        success: function() {
                            alert("done");  
                        }
                    });

                    $('#show').dialog({
                        height:500,
                        width:800,
                        buttons:{
                            "OK":function(){
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            },
                            "Cancel":function(){
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: you can use same id selector to get values.. `var name =$('#name').val();  var add = $('#address').val();` Element is just hidden but is still there in your html, until you refresh page or redirect.

Comment: but how do i display them ?My code is retrieving the values but not posting them or you can say displaying them .@DineshPatil

Comment: Your code is missing external js included.. can you share your code on jsfiddle or any other editing tool? it wont take much time.. and i can directly give you the running code..

Comment: @DineshPatil , I dont have any idea how to add jquery plugins in js fiddle..My code is running on my machine ,it is displaying the dialog box on click but the only thing is that it is not displaying the name and address in "show dialog box".And it is showing me a undefined index 'keyname' error.And is my tried fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/payalsuthar/odq5xto2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this-

```
     function callback(value) {
            if (value) {
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var add = $('#address').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'display.php', 
                    data: {keyname: name,keyadd: add},
                    success: function() {
                        alert("done");  
                         $("#show b").html("Name : "+name);
                         $("#show p").html("Address : "+add);
                    }
                });

                $('#show').dialog({
                    height:500,
                    width:800,
                    buttons:{
                        "OK":function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        "Cancel":function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your callback data is wrong:

`data: {keyname: com,keyadd: add},` -> `data: {'keyname': name,'keyadd': add},`

Try change this.